# Remove text decoration line under image link

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to remove this line from images which is showing up in IE

[image]

I have removed the images borders and text-decoration from the links using css

```
body img {
    border:none;
}
a img {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

I can't figure out what else could be causing it.

It's not an underscore it is linking to the facebook page.

Comment: post your code or link or try to create jsfiddle

Comment: Looks to me like you have an underscore between the images in your html.

Comment: box-shadow???? check plz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The decoration appears between the images and is therefore not selected by `a img`. Try this:

```
a { text-decoration:none; }
```

As stated by [Mr. Alien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315776/remove-annoying-line-under-image-link-in-ie#comment28608923_19315833) you should consider to wrap this section somehow, so you can use a more specific selector, e.g.:

```
.share-buttons a { text-decoration:none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like a space between your images, the underline will be on the anchor

try adding

```
a, a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
```

Comment: Note: This is an element selector, it will affect all the links on your website, to be specific, assign a class to the parent element and use something like `.parent_class a {text-decoration: none;}`